# update partial view mvc3 with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have javascript function for update partial view. Now i need to update partial view that take one value and i cant do it :(

here is my function that works:

```
function clearData() {
    var urlclear = '@Url.Action("Clear", "Cart")';
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlclear,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#AjaxUpdate').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

and if i put:

```
function clearData(id) {
    var urlclear = '@Url.Action("Clear", "Cart", new {ID = id})';
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlclear,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#AjaxUpdate').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

it tells me that id is undefined.

Can someone please tell me what im doing wrong.

thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var urlclear = '@Url.Action("Clear", "Cart")' + "?ID=" + id;
```

OR

```
var urlclear = '@Url.Action("Clear", "Cart")' + "/" + id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
var urlclear = '@Url.Action("Clear", "Cart", new {ID = id})';
```

with

```
var urlclear = "@Url.Action("Clear", "Cart")/"+id;
```